# Apache solr fuzzy search on list values

Tags: solr, fuzzy-search

Enviornment - solr-8.9.0

To implement fuzzy search on column "name" (fuzzy search for 'alaistiar~') of csv file in apache solr i am issueing following query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:'alaistiar~'&wt=json
```

To implement fuzzy search on column "name" (fuzzy search for 'shanka~') of csv file in apache solr

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:'shanka~'&wt=json
```

May i combine both the above query in a single and find out the documents?

My first http request is doing fuzzy search for value alaistiar~ on name colums and giving some score value and second http request is for shanka~. When i combine both with 'OR' operator Will it behave same as they are individual request.Acutally My purpose is that i dont want to invoke multiple http request for multiple names, Also i want fuzzy search name in output indicating that this document is for name alaistiar~ and this document is for name shanka~

I have loaded a csv file having 4 columns(Size-5GB.) with 100 milion records. .csv file has following column names -

```
'name', 'father_name', 'date_of_passing','admission_number'
```

I have created index on column 'name. To do this i have executed following curl request on managed-schema(solr-8.9.0, jdk-11.0.12)

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"name","type":"text_general","stored":true,"indexed":true }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/schema
 curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"father_name","type":"text_general","stored":true,"indexed":false }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/schema
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"date_of_passing","type":"pdate","stored":true,"indexed":false }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/schema
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{"add-field":{"name":"admission_number","type":"text_general","stored":true,"indexed":false }}' http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/schema
```

Is this a right way to create index on 1 column(only on name) as described above?

Now i have list of 1 milion names. On each name i have to do fuzzy-search(column:name) on already loaded data. In the output, for each name I have to return list of java objects including all 4 columns of .csv file.

Note- In output I also have to include name which was supplied as input(in where clause).
For each name, i am doing fuzzy search as follows :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:'alaistiar~'&wt=json.
```

To do this i have to execute 1 milion http request, which i dont want. Instead of executing 1milion http request, May i do in a single http request?

I understand that 'OR operator will not solve my problem because i will not able to group output documents on the basis of name which was passed as a input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could unify the queries by using "OR":

name:alaistiar~ OR name:shanka~

http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:alaistiar~ OR name:shanka~&wt=json

You could omit "OR" if your default operator is "OR". The query would look like:

name:alaistiar~ name:shanka~

http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/select?indent=on&q=name:alaistiar~  name:shanka~&wt=json

Of course the "space" should be escaped in URL.

Hello, again. After you edited your question, it is more clear what you are looking for:

1. only 1 query for 1 mil names
2. see in the result which response to which name corresponds

There is a solutions, but you have to do some post processing. You can use a POST request with a json with params (for 1) and you can use hit highlighting (for 2) like I did here:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/bigboxstore/query?hl.fl=name&hl.simple.post=</b>&hl.simple.pre=<b>&hl=on' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d 'json={"query":"name:alaistiar~ name:shanka~"}'
```

The answer contains two parts: the first one with the result and the second one with the id and the highlights -> you will have to pair them up on id after receiving the response.

Comment: thankx for reply! My first http request is doing fuzzy search for value alaistiar~ on name colums and giving some score value and second http request is for shanka~. When i combine both with 'OR' operator Will it behave same as they are individual request. Means will it not give highest score when document has name as 'alaistiar shanka'. Acutally My purpose is that i dont want to invoke multiple http request for multiple names, Also i want fuzzy search name in output  indicating that this document is for name alaistiar~ and this document is for name shanka~.

Comment: @user595014: Yes if you combine with `or`, it will give highest score when document has name as 'alaistiar shanka'. This as I understand you dont want. You are looking for something like Query batching https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1093 which is not implemented yet.

Comment: A patch was created for this feature but never got merged. You may want to download the patch and apply to your local solr instance and test it that helps. But as the patch is quite old now, you may have to modify code to make it work with latest solr versions. However, go on this path only if absolutely necessary.

Comment: @OanaB ...Thankx for reply! In the output it is showing highlights with id and name(which was in output document). How will i know name written in output is fuzzy-search for 'alaistiar' / 'shanka'.

Comment: Hello, @user595014 I now realize that you cannot pair up the results.